# Solution of $y''(x)+y(x)=0$, why is it $y=A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We want to solve $y''(x)+y(x)=0$. We are looking for solutions of the form $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$. Then, we get $$(\lambda ^2+1)e^{\lambda x}\iff \lambda ^2+1=0\iff \lambda =\pm i.$$
Therefore, the general solution is given by $$y(x)=Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}.$$

But why in my solution they say that it's of the form $$y(x)=C\cos(x)+D\sin(x) \ \ ?$$

How can I pass from $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$ to $C\cos(x)+D\sin(x)$ ? I know that $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ and $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-x}}{2i}$. Therefore, I can replace these value in $C\cos(x)+D\sin(x)$ and find $A$ and $B$ s.t. it's equal to $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$.

But I'm really asking : how do I know that $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$ can be written in the form of $C\cos(x)+D\sin(x)$ ? Because at my exam I had 0 point on $5$ because I wrote the solution as $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix}$, but it's correct, no ?

Comment: Euler's Formula: $e^{i \theta}= \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is also correct. You really just need to substitute in the following manner:
$$Ae^{ix}+Be^{-ix} = \frac{A+B}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})+\frac{A-B}{2}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) = (A+B) \cos x + i(A-B)\sin x$$

Now this is equivalent to $C \cos x + D \sin x,$ since given $A,B$ we can find unique $C,D$ and vice versa.  (This is due to the fact that $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 
i & -i
\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible.)

Comment: So at the end, $A-B$ must be in $i\mathbb R$ ? Because I'm a bit confuse in the sense that $Ae^{ix}+B^{-ix}$ must be in $\mathbb R$ or can be in $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: That depends on the question itself. If you seek real solutions, then yes indeed $\Re A  = \Re B$. Note that also you need to require that $\Im A = -\Im B$, so actually $B=\bar{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $e^{ix}=\cos x +i\sin x$ and $e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x$. Then
$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}.$$

Comment: I edited my question. I know this trick. I was more asking on why from $Ae^{ix}+Be^{-x}$ is not a correct solution, and it has to be written as $A\cos(x)+B\sin(x)$ ?

Comment: Your solution is correct if you were working on complex numbers. If your framework is the real setting, your solution is not correct. BUT... this is an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for all real-valued solutions to this equation, all you need is to find two linearly independent real-valued solutions (because the space of solutions form a vector space over $\mathbb R$).

As it turns out, a direct way to find these solutions is to momentarily consider complex-valued functions. If you solve for complex functions, as you did, now your only task is to select 2 real-valued functions among those complex solutions (if any). In this case, they happen to be $\cos(x), \sin(x)$, and they suffice to describe all real-valued solutions.

If you do not want to work over the complex valued-functions (which I would not see why), you can assume, for instance, that the solutions will have a Taylor expansion around 0. This is, you look for solutions of the form

$$f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i.$$

When you plug this to the equation, you end up with a recurrence relation on the $a_i$'s. Solving this recurrence relation will give the Taylor representations of the functions you are looking, without seeing directly those complex valued functions.